# How to sort and filter a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, return, element

I have a list of list in Python that I want to sort based on two categories. The sorted list should have the lowest number in the last position and also the first element has to be greater than 400. I want to return the top 3 from the list.

```
x_list = [['422', '324', '733443'], ['342', '654', '674335'], 
         ['953', '456', '828854'], ['345', '886', '446678'], 
         ['3224', '533', '654333'], ['7545', '5567', '369990']]
```

It should return like this:

```
result = [['7545', '5567', '369990'], ['3224', '533', '654333'], ['422', '324', '733443']]
```

I have tried using the following code, but cannot combine the two conditions to sort the list:

```
result= []
result += sorted(x_list, key=lambda x: int(x[-1]))[:3]
```

Can anyone plz help me to solve this? Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the requirements. You mean, you want to sort and also filter, to remove elements where the first inner-element is less than 400?

Comment: @kojiro Yes correct

Comment: i think so, filtering is necessary too in this csae, yes.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Can u plz show me how to do that? I'm new to Python actually

Comment: np, I added an example below, but looks like there are other ones as well :-)

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter and also https://pythonguides.com/python-list-comprehension-using-if-else/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first *filter* the list to only retain values where first element is greater than 400, and then *sort* the final result by ascending order based on last element, as you originally had it. For example:

```py
x_list = [['422', '324', '733443'], ['342', '654', '674335'],
         ['953', '456', '828854'], ['345', '886', '446678'],
         ['3224', '533', '654333'], ['7545', '5567', '369990']]

x_list2 = [x for x in x_list if int(x[0]) > 400]
x_list2.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[2]))
x_list2 = x_list2[:3]

print(x_list2)
# [['7545', '5567', '369990'], ['3224', '533', '654333'], ['422', '324', '733443']]
```

Or you can also sort and filter in a single step as well:

```py
x_list = [['422', '324', '733443'], ['342', '654', '674335'],
         ['953', '456', '828854'], ['345', '886', '446678'],
         ['3224', '533', '654333'], ['7545', '5567', '369990']]

x_list2 = sorted((x for x in x_list if int(x[0]) > 400), key=lambda x: int(x[2]))[:3]

print(x_list2)
# [['7545', '5567', '369990'], ['3224', '533', '654333'], ['422', '324', '733443']]
```

Comment: The question used `int` to convert the string to a number, but you just use a string comparison.  That means `9` will come *after* `369990`.

Comment: whoops - good catch, thanks. just fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this code:

```
filter_first = [el for el in x_list if int(el[0]) > 400]
sorted(filter_first, key=lambda el: el[-1])
```

This gives me

```
[['7545', '5567', '369990'], ['3224', '533', '654333'], ['422', '324', '733443'], ['953', '456', '828854']]
```

which is different from what you claimed you wanted the output to be, but I think it meets all your stated requirements. Can you explain the '953' sublist?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a customizable function:

```
def sort_filtered(list_, key=lambda x: x[2], filter_=lambda x: x[0] > 400, n=3):   
    # Turn values into floats so we can sort them
    float_list = [[float(x) for x in y] for y in list_]
    return [x for x in sorted(float_list, key=key) if filter_][:n]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x_list = [['422', '324', '733443'], ['342', '654', '674335'],
         ['953', '456', '828854'], ['345', '886', '446678'],
         ['3224', '533', '654333'], ['7545', '5567', '369990']]

x_list = [a for a in x_list if float(a[0]) > 400]  # Filters out values <= 400
x_list.sort(key=lambda x : x[2])  # Sorts by the last element
x_list = x_list[:3]  # Only keeps the first 3 values
print(x_list)
```